# C# UDP communication ending connection when no answer received

Tags: c#, .net, networking, udp

I'm writing simple app for dynamic communicating with arduinos over UDP.

I'm stucked during writing UDP class in C# pc app.

I have problem with ending fuction after not receiving answer from client. If I'm connecting with client which is on, there is no problem, app is runing nice and smooth after receiving answer from it.

```
STRING_operations str = new STRING_operations();

    static int communicationPort = 8888;
    string[] arduinoPool = new string[64];

    private void populateArduinoPool()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            arduinoPool[i] = "192.168.1." + Convert.ToString(170 + i);
        }
    }

    private string mainCommunication(string vIPAdsress, string Message)
    {
        string answer = string.Empty;
        int port = communicationPort;

        Console.WriteLine("IP address: " + vIPAdsress);
        Console.WriteLine("Message to sent: " + Message);

        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.sendString(Message));
        Byte[] receiveBytes = null;

        var IP = IPAddress.Parse(vIPAdsress);
        var udpClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        udpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
        udpClient.SendTimeout = 1000;
        var sendEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, port);
        var receiveEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, port);
        var clientReturn = new UdpClient(port);

            udpClient.SendTo(sendBytes, sendEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent");
            try { 
            receiveBytes = clientReturn.Receive(ref receiveEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Message is being receiving");

            if (receiveBytes == null || receiveBytes.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No answer");
                ;
            }

                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes));
                answer = str.trimString(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes));
                Console.WriteLine("Trimed answer: " + answer);

            udpClient.Disconnect(true);
            return answer; }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return e.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void populateComboBox(ComboBox CB1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Populating arduino pool");
        populateArduinoPool();
        string message = str.sendString("HELLO");

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to communicate with: " + arduinoPool[i]);
            if (mainCommunication(arduinoPool[i], message) == "YO")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Established");
                CB1.Items.Add(arduinoPool[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool checkIfActive(ComboBox CB1)
    {
        string message = str.sendString("HELLO"); ;
        if (mainCommunication(CB1.SelectedText.ToString(), message) == "YO")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: why you used of UDP? you must use of TCP for this case!

Comment: You are right sir. I must have stucked in the middle of freak twister. thank you for advice :)

Comment: Problem is solved, I'm detecting devices with simple ping method.